How do uninstall Anaconda3 on Windows 11 pro when there is an "failed to run pre_uninstall" error?
I am trying to uninstall Anaconda because I could not boot up the program and through the best case was to uninstall and reinstall the program. I use it predominately for the Jupyter Notebooks. I have windows 11 pro installed on the computer.
The last time I used Anaconda, I believe there was an option to update it, but I clicked the option to update the navigator on the next rendition. Which lead to this case. And there was no indication at all that the program was trying to update.
In trying to get it to uninstall, I tried using the official method of going to the settings and selecting the uninstall button from the installed apps menu in the settings. However, when I try to run the uninstall program, the Anaconda pop up window shows up and runs for a little bit before it gets to the "Running pre_uninstall scripts..." portion. An error pops up and says that it failed to run the pre_uninstall, and gives me 3 options, abort, retry, or ignore.
What is the best way to proceed with fixing this?
enter image description here
